# Javascript how hidden div onclick of phrase

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to make it so that when I click on a term, a `<div></div>` box is revealed. Here's my code:

```
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div><img src="paste-66846870995528.jpg" /></div></a>
```

Right now I have it so the default is that if `a>div` then the div is hidden:

```
a>div { display: none; }
```

And I only show the `div` if the `<a></a>` is hovered:

```
a:hover>div {
border: 1px solid black;
font-weight:normal;
font-family:garamond;
font-size: 14px;
display: block;
text-align:center;}
```

However, as I mentioned earlier I like to make it so that when I click on a term, the div is revealed.

I saw a tutorial that used this:

```
<script>
function clickDiv() {
  var x = document.getElementById("clickable");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

<a onclick="clickDiv()"><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves,</u><div id="clickable"><img src="paste-66846870995528.jpg" /></div></a>
```

But this just displays the very first phrase's image, not the image associated with the specific phrase I click.

Comment: In your example you don't provide any element with an `id="clickable"`

Comment: I just got the example to work but anything I click just opens the first image in my code, when I want it to open the specific image coupled with the <a> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a true toggle, this will work:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  var el = evt.target;
  if (el.tagName === 'U') {
    el = el.parentElement;
  }
  if (el.tagName === 'A') {
    el.classList.toggle('open');
  }
});
```

```css
a > div {
  display: none;
}

a.open > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  font: 14px garamond;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
```

You would place in your `<div>` whatever you wanted.

The event handler happens on the `<u>` tag so we need to go up to its parent, which is the `<a>` tag. Then we toggle the class `'open'`.

If you want the newly opened item to close the others then try this:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  var el = evt.target;
  if (el.tagName === 'U') {
    el = el.parentElement;
  }
  var oldEl = document.querySelector('a.open');
  if (oldEl && oldEl !== el) {
    oldEl.classList.remove('open');
  }
  
  if (el.tagName === 'A') {
    el.classList.toggle('open');
  }
});
```

```css
a > div {
  display: none;
}

a.open > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  font: 14px garamond;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
<a><u>ilioinguinal and genitofemoral nerves</u><div>Inside DIV</div></a><br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this with jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $('.class-of-a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        var target = $(this).attr('data-target');

        $(target).css({display: 'block'});
    });
});
```

Then you set your  attribute to

```
<a data-target="#targetID">Link</a>
```

Which would make the chosen targetID to be displayed when specific  is pressed.